# Rust: Are Vectors and Arrays sometimes interchangeable?

Tags: rust

I'm using the [crypto::sha2::sha256](https://docs.rs/rust-crypto/0.2.36/crypto/sha2/struct.Sha256.html) package which implements the [Digest trait](https://docs.rs/rust-crypto/0.2.36/crypto/digest/trait.Digest.html#tymethod.result).

The documentation says that the `result()` method on the Digest trait takes in a vector and will write the result of the hashing function into that vector.

However, I am passing in an array that looks like this: `[u32; 32]`.

I'm not getting any compiling errors despite the type mismatch. I don't understand why this is allowed. Is it possible that in Rust sometimes arrays and vectors are interchangeable? Or is something else going on?

Comment: If you take a closer look at the signature of the [`result()`](https://docs.rs/rust-crypto/0.2.36/crypto/digest/trait.Digest.html#tymethod.result) function you'll see that it actually takes a [`slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.slice.html)

Comment: @Herohtar thanks for clarifying that!

If anyone else is curious:
The `result()` method expects `&mut [u8]`. This is a mutable slice and Rust can silently coerce arrays into slices.

I still don't understand why it says in the Arguments section of the documentation for `result()` that it expects a vector when it expects a slice... Do you perhaps know the answer to this one too, @Herohtar?

Comment: @StevesyZissou Most likely, whoever wrote the documentation made a mistake, or the function used to take a vector and this got changed but the documentation wasn’t updated.

Comment: Makes sense -- just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something else! Thanks @mcarton